# How to make a triangle checkerboard pattern?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a checkerboard of right triangles with loops, but I am not sure how to go about it. I'm trying to make it so that the user inputs 2 integers and a character, to indicate the length, size, and character to fill the triangles in. Input 3 5 w would give:

```
w
ww
www
wwww
wwwww
w    w
ww   ww
www  www
wwww wwww
wwwwwwwwww
w    w    w
ww   ww   ww
www  www  www
wwww wwww wwww
wwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

So far I have made a single right triangle, but I am not sure if that is the correct way to start this. I am also stuck on how to make the checkerboard pattern. I am new to Java and it is difficult for me to figure out how to start programs off.

```
public class Triangle {
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
            System.out.print("w");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
  }
```

Comment: Post code please. Otherwise this thread will be closed.

Comment: Have you tried any coding? Paste it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(5, 3, 'w');
    }

    private static void print(int h, int H, char x) {
        //h for height of the triangle, H for the height of pattern and x the char.
        for(int n = 1; n <= H; n++) {
            printTriangle(n, h, x);
        }
    }

    private static void printTriangle(int numTriangles, int h, char x) {
        for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            //Let's print the line in the triangles with spaces.
            for(int n = 0; n < numTriangles - 1; n++) {
                for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(x);
                }
                for(int j = i+1; j < h; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            //The last one has no spaces so:
            for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(x);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int k=1;k<=3;k++) {
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
                for(int x=1;x<=k;x++) {
                    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                        System.out.print("W");
                    }
                    for(int y=1;y<=5-i;y++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```